# UIScrollView does not scroll anymore after the view re-appear

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a scrollview on the main view after the display of another view the scroll stop scrolling.

On view appear I tried to refresh the scroll but no luck

calling this:

```
-(void)refreshScrollView{

    NSLog(@"scroll Content Height %f",answerScolledHeight );
    NSLog(@"scroll View Height %f", scrollView1.frame.size.height );
    [scrollView1 setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, answerScolledHeight)];
    [scrollView1 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

}
```

It reads the right values without working:

```
2013-03-21 17:56:01.434 ----[38464:14003] scroll Content Height 256.000000
2013-03-21 17:56:01.434 ----[38464:14003] scroll View Height 194.000000
```

The problem comes after the display of the settings view:

```
 SettingsController* controller1 =  (SettingsController *)[self getSettingsViewController];
        [self presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:YES];
```

And when the settings is closed the scroll does not work anymore

```
- (IBAction)doClose:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The viewDidAppear, I try to run some commands the first time to limitate the problems as I am using ECslidingViewController (a wipe menu)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      if (!isActive){
        answerUpY = self.answerView.frame.origin.y;
        answerDownY = self.questionBackground.frame.origin.y +self.questionBackground.frame.size.height - self.answerToggle.frame.size.height - PADDING_1;
        isActive = TRUE;
        [self slidingControllerAppear];

    }else{
        [self refreshScrollView];

    }
}
```

Comment: by any chance your scrollview is below other view ?

Comment: Don't think so as this funcion is scrollViewWillBeginDragging triggered

Comment: What do you have in you viewWillAppear:, viewDidAppear viewWillDissappear: viewDidDissappear methods? Do you use gesture recognizer?

Comment: No I am not using this methods, I have few gesture recognizer, any bug connected with that?